# Cypher query with group by inside aggregation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I created a cypher query which returns list of people in country & some avg calculation:

```
Match (people:People)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(address:Address), (people)-[:SOME]->(calc)
RETURN address.country as name, count(*) as count, avg(calc.value) as value
```

Which returns for instance:

```
name, count, value
PL  , 5    , 10
UK  , 3    , 20
US  , 6    , 30
DE  , 3    , 40
```

What I'm trying to achieve right now is to group a few of them in some custom groups.
For instance, if the country is PL & UK return it AS Custom:

```
name   , count, value
Custom , 8    , 15
US     , 6    , 30
DE     , 3    , 40
```

I was able to achieve it by creating two separate queries one where I specified:
`WHERE address.country IN ['PL','UK']` and second with negation, and I combined it after that.
Is there any easier solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with a `CASE` statement:

```
Match (people:People)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(address:Address), (people)-[:SOME]->(calc)
RETURN CASE WHEN address.country in ['PL','UK'] THEN 'Custom' ELSE address.country END as name, 
  count(*) as count, avg(calc.value) as value
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a great game changed. I will test that in an hour and accept answer if everything will be fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom name map and the [COALESCE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce) function. You could even pass the (possibly empty) map as a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) (instead of defining it statically) if the custom name mapping can change.

```
WITH {PL: 'Custom', UK: 'Custom'} AS cMap
MATCH (calc)<-[:SOME]-(people:People)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(address:Address)
RETURN
  COALESCE(cMap[address.country], address.country) as name, 
  COUNT(*) AS count,
  AVG(calc.value) AS value
```